# How to create non-entity(custom) Index in Search API

Tags: 8, search

I'm working on a website that calls another external web service. I want to collect those data somewhere on the D8 website. then based on them I'll provide some REST endpoints for the FE layer.

one solution can create a custom entity or custom content type and on cron run  get data from the external web service and store them into the custom entity and custom content type then they will be indexed and will be available on the search_api to write a REST endpoint on them but the problem is that structure of the data is complicated and I don't want to engage drupal entity in the project.

**my question is how can I create a custom search API index programmatically without having content type or custom entity?**